# Delta pulse approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, simulations, perturbation-theory

Let us suppose we have an harmonic oscillator hamiltonian, with a controlling term $xu(t)$:
\begin{equation} H(t)=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2 - u(t)x \end{equation}
As stated in "A. G. Butkovskiy and Y. I. Samoilenko, Control of Quantum-Mechanical
Processes and Systems" an optimal $u(t)$ in order to maximize the probability transition from e.g. $|0\rangle$ to $|1\rangle$ must satisfy the condition:
\begin{equation} \left|\int_0^Tu(t)e^{-it}dt\right|=\sqrt{2}\end{equation}
An example of $u(t)$ is a $\sqrt{2}\delta(t)$ pulse. How can one generate a $\delta(t)$ pulse in, for example, a simulation? Which approximation should I use?

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia page on the delta function?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I cannot exploit integrals in my simulation. Only gaussian-like functions eventually with periodic modulation. So I thought I could use a gaussian with very low $\sigma$, but I am still not convinced by the results.

Comment: You should post about the details of your simulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gaussian should work as long as the area under it is unity and it is as short as possible in the simulation.  A rectangular pulse pulse of height w and width 1/w will also work with w made as large as possible.

Both of these pulses converge to a delta function as their height goes to infinity.